# Rails 4 routing a value besides :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I either have an issue with my link_to code in my view or my route.  I am trying to pass in a non primary key value from a view and do a query using that value.  No matter what I do rails always just takes the :id of that table as its only param.

Here is my view

```
 <td> <%= link_to c.app_version_id, compliance_suite_path(:app_version_id => c.app_version_id) %></td>
```

My Route

```
  resources :suites, :only => [:index] do
member do
  get 'report'
end
  member do
  get 'compliance', param: :app_version_id
end
```

end

If I do a rake routes I get

compliance_suite GET  /suites/:id/compliance(.:format)             suites#compliance {:param=>:app_version_id}

Here is my controller which right now is just trying to view the prams list

```
      def compliance

    Rails.logger.info "***********PARAMS PARAMS *******************"
    Rails.logger.info {params.inspect}
   end
```

I do have other methods in that controller that use the :ID I just have this one method I want to use another value an app version id to do a query.  So I don't want the entire controller to use this other id just 1 method.  The value I want is in my view I can see it in my table.  In my controller its always just the :id and never the app_version_id.

Its either my route or my link_to?

Comment: did you add `:app_version_id` to allowed params in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your route is a nested member route, rails expects the id of the parent. You don't really need to include the params clause in your route. It would be better to change your route to reflect your intentions by including the app_version_id in the route.

routes.rb

```
get 'suite/:app_version_id/compliance', to: 'suites#compliance', as: 'compliance_suite'
```

Comment: So I need to pull my route apart so the compliance path is not nested?

Comment: It depends if the controller action needs the parent instance - that would be one way to do it. Then your link would include the app_version_id as the only param. The code I included would use the existing route minus the param clause i.e. member do get compliance end.

Comment: So after re reading I put it back the way it was with the nested route and passed in 2 values via my link_to and I get the app_version however it wants to automatically redirect using the :id  in the url like so -> Started GET "/suites/13/compliance?app_version_id=9"     -- 13 is the app id  app version id is 9.  I have no code to redirect from the controller so my guess is the route does that?  can I correct that I want this /suites/9/compliance   -- based on the app_version_id

Comment: I don't understand what your last comment means. Because the controller  compliant action has no code in it, rails will automatically redirect to views/suites/compliance.html if there is such a file otherwise it will probably throw an error. Can you be more precise about 'it wants to automatically redirect using the id..' what does it refer to? where does it want to redirect to?

Comment: sure sorry.  With no code in the controller except a print of the params the app redirects to --> http://localhost:3000/suites/13/compliance?app_version_id=9          13 is the Suite ID.  That is what I do not want to use.  What I want to use to go to the compliance page is 9 which is the app_ver_id.  so can I have my controller tell it to redirect to compliance page with the app_ver_id as its path  /suites/9/compliance

Comment: I am doing this because there is one instance where I don't care about the suites I want all suite that have a certain app version to run a report.  so I don't want to have the suite id in the path /suites/13/compliance  I want the app_version in that path  /suites/9/compliance

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to set the id to the app_version_id, compliance_suite_path(id: app_version_id ). You need to use the :id because the route is expecting the named param 'id'. Ideally you should amend the routes to better reflect your intention. Gimme a sec and I'll amend my answer.

Comment: I amended the answer to include the updated route to what (I hope I understand) you're trying to do.

Comment: When I use in my link_to   compliance_suite_path(id: c.app_version_id) I get a routing error --> ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"compliance", :controller=>"suites", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):

Comment: That means c.app_version_id is nil. Are you sure app_version_id is set for whatever c is? Did you change the route? and use your original link_to c.app_version_id, compliance_suite_path(:app_version_id => c.app_version_id)

Comment: I appreciate the help I don't want to drag this on and waste peoples time.  my app version is not null but I am sure I can figure it out this is some stupid issue where I am off by 1 word someplace.  thank you again